# How do I concatenate two matrices of the type Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Matrix?

Tags: c#, matrix, uwp

I'm doing a UWP implementation of a class I have for Android and there don't seem to be equivalents for the PreRotate, PreTranslate, PreScale, and PreConcat functions used to preconcat matrices in the Android.Graphics.Matrix class. Is this possible or should I be using transform groups instead?

The concrete problem is my class will be getting a series transformations and needs to combine them to transform points.

Answer (score 1):

Try this helper method on Matrix multiplication found in [Layout transform in Windows 8 WinRT XAML](http://igrali.com/2012/09/17/layout-transform-in-windows-8-winrt-xaml/)

```
/// <summary>
/// Implements WPF's Matrix.Multiply on Silverlight.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="matrix1">First matrix.</param>
/// <param name="matrix2">Second matrix.</param>
/// <returns>Multiplication result.</returns>
private static Matrix MatrixMultiply(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2)
{
    // WPF equivalent of following code:
    // return Matrix.Multiply(matrix1, matrix2);
    return new Matrix(
        (matrix1.M11 * matrix2.M11) + (matrix1.M12 * matrix2.M21),
        (matrix1.M11 * matrix2.M12) + (matrix1.M12 * matrix2.M22),
        (matrix1.M21 * matrix2.M11) + (matrix1.M22 * matrix2.M21),
        (matrix1.M21 * matrix2.M12) + (matrix1.M22 * matrix2.M22),
        ((matrix1.OffsetX * matrix2.M11) + (matrix1.OffsetY * matrix2.M21)) + matrix2.OffsetX,
        ((matrix1.OffsetX * matrix2.M12) + (matrix1.OffsetY * matrix2.M22)) + matrix2.OffsetY);
}
```